# How to do Proper SSR and Data Fetching in Next.js 14 App Router?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, app-router

I recently transitioned from a page router to an app router due to its advanced features. However, I've encountered a dilemma and find myself perplexed regarding the implementation of SSR and data fetching.

### The Problem:

The documentation suggests that, instead of using getServerSideProps() or similar methods, we can simply fetch data using the old fetch function with additional parameters like "{cache: 'no-store'}." However, I'm uncertain about how to create a universal helper function for fetching GraphQL data that can be used across all pages.

### The Confusion:

Next.js advises against using hooks within components, as components are SSR by default. To utilize hooks, the recommendation is to include "use client" in the component. But, if we aim to fetch data as SSR and then store it in a hook, will the fetched data still maintain its SSR characteristics due to the use of "use client" within the component?

It would be better if you wrote a function to fetch data as SSR along with hooks to store data.
Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

this is the helper function I was using across the app in the previous page router.

```
<pre>
export async function storefront(params) {
    const response = await  fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL, { 
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Another-Property": "Something here", },
       body: JSON.stringify({ params }),
     });
    return response.json();
   }
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any data fetching that are called within "use client" directive will be fetched on the client side. All initial UI will be still rendered on the server, then hydrated on the client. So if you call the data fetching inside a hook, which will require you to be in a client component, the UI will still render on the server side as much as possible, but there will be no data, because data will be fetched once everything hits the client, and then rehydrated.

"But, if we aim to fetch data as SSR and then store it in a hook"

I don't think that is possible, as you cannot pass something like that to the client, you can, however, fetch data on the server and then pass it to the client. The "use client" directive doesn't mean client side rendering, it is still server side rendered.

The below code sample is completely server side rendered.

```
export async function Page() {
  const myDataQ = await fetch (....)
  const data = await myDataQ.json()
  return <ClientComp data={data}/>
}

#/ClientComp.tsx
"use client"
export const ClientComp = ({data}) => { 
  return <div> {data} </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I have a follow-up question. In the context of building a real-world application, how should we approach it? Given that we'll be making numerous server-side rendering (SSR) fetch requests, it seems that each time we fetch new data, we would require an additional component to handle the SSR fetch and then provide the data to the client component as a prop. What would be the most optimal and organized approach to this scenario? For instance, if I need to interact with four different endpoints, how should I go about handling it efficiently?

Comment: You don't have to pass data to new client components, as long as the component doesn't use hooks. But if your client component uses hooks or interactive JS, then the above would be the approach. This replaces the old getServerSideProps etc.. and imo its much cleaner. If you have 4 different endpoints, you can have them fetch separately in parallel in their own components via <Suspense/>. Or you can just fetch them all at once. it is up to you.

Comment: can you show me some code examples? it will help me alot!
i'm building a headless app with nextjs, so for that I'll need to fetch different things eg (blogs, posts)

Comment: If you're building a blogging website, you can use ISR. Read more here 
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
Personally I will fetch data server side and have it rendered on server side as well for a blog site. Give your fetches a tag like ["blog:blogId"], with auto revalidate to 3 hour. With the tag you can also manually revalidate it whenever you like.

Comment: Could you provide guidance on how to implement server-side rendering (SSR) to fetch products and utilize React hooks for filtering on the same shop page? Additionally, do you use platforms like Telegram or Discord for further discussion?

Comment: I'm kinda busy irl rn. But I would use react-query, on the server side, fetch initial products, inject the initial product into react-query's useQuery initialData prop, also set queryKey[..., filters]. with that you're pretty much done.

Comment: I think your code snippet is not completely server-side rendered. You just put the "use client" directive in a SFC file and then fetched the data in SSR-based script. This is a recommended thing that the Next docs also mentioned. It says that you can put the directive in any section that does not need to be rendered in server side.